# Android: What's the Usage of SqliteCursorFactory in SqliteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm wondering whats the usage of  `SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory` in the SqliteOpenHelper.

According to the Documentation:

Class Overview:
Used to allow returning sub-classes of Cursor when calling query.

But i can use a Cursor like this in my SQLiteopenhelper class by passing `null` as the CursorFactory Argument.

```
Cursor c = db.query("person", null,suchStr,null,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for the cases when you want to extend the `Cursor` class and then you u can use `CursorFactory` in order to return you own `Cursor` implementation. some example code http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory

Comment: but why with an factory
wouldnt MyCursor my = db.query("person", null,suchStr,null,null,null,null); also work?

Comment: because on regular call to the db you get back what android intends to returns you which is regular cursor. to get your "special" cursor you need to use CursorFactory. I don't see any reason why you should though (-: